# Obtener primer valor de un array en javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, google-maps

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"> </script>

<script>
    var coordenadas;
    function testAjax() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://dev.datos.ua.es/uapi/5QGUfP3UM6j5VXERjKvU/datasets/11/data', type: 'GET',
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {                        
                   coordenadas = item.bbox.split(',');
                   console.log(coordenadas[1], coordenadas[0]);   

                });
            }
        });
    }

</script> 
<script>testAjax();</script>
```

Teniendo ese código, me salen muchas latitudes y longitudes, una lista de todas ellas pero me gustaria sacar solo la primera pareja de longitud y latitud de todas, ya que solo consigo que me salgan todas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Gracias!, pero de los datos del jsonp los necesito todos, una vez que los tenga, los quiero usar individualmente cada pareja para ponerlos en un mapa

Ah!, entonces lo que quieres no es sólo el primer resultado, sino los primeros 2 resultados de cada resultado (tu pregunta está hecha de manera confusa).  En cuyo caso, sólo debes declarar un Array, y dentro del `$.each` utilizar la función `push()`.

Ejemplo:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"> </script>

<script>
    var coordenadas;
    var buffer = new Array();
    function testAjax() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://dev.datos.ua.es/uapi/5QGUfP3UM6j5VXERjKvU/datasets/11/data',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {                        
                   coordenadas = item.bbox.split(',');
                   buffer.push([coordenadas[1], coordenadas[0]]);   
                });
            }
        });
    }

</script> 
<script>
    testAjax();
</script>
```

De esta manera vas a poder acceder a los valores del array 2D de manera más sencilla.

```
buffer[0][1]
```

Cabe destacar que como es una petición asíncrona, si colocas...

```
console.log(buffer[x][x])
```

Luego de `testAjax()`, no va a funcionar por temas de tiempo ya que es todo asíncrono, de forma tal que vas a poder acceder sólo desde otra función declarada cuya ejecución se dé mediante un evento onclick, onkeypress u otro evento.

Comment: De momento no me va de esa forma... me salen como repetidos.. probare de mas formas

Answer (score 0):

El código está bien, sólo tienes que modificar ésto...

```
success: function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {                        
        coordenadas = item.bbox.split(',');
        console.log(coordenadas[1], coordenadas[0]);   
    });
}
```

Por ésto...

```
success: function (data) {                    
    coordenadas = data[0].bbox.split(',');
    console.log(coordenadas[1], coordenadas[0]);
}
```

Comment: Gracias!, pero de los datos del jsonp los necesito todos, una vez que los tenga, los quiero usar individualmente cada pareja para ponerlos en un mapa